# MySql Not starting even when status is ok ubuntu lampp

Tags: apache2, mysql, php, lamp

I am a Newbie to Ubuntu. I just installed the xampp Linux version through `xampp-linux-1.8.3-4-installer.run` file.

Following are the commands that I used:

```
cd /home/sammy/Downloads 
sudo chmod +x xampp-linux-1.8.3-4-installer.run
sudo -s -H 
sudo ./xampp-linux-1.8.3-4-installer.run

sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

It's done okay... then when I tried to access phpmyadmin it gives me following error:

```
Error MySQL said: Documentation #2002 
- No such file or directory The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not
correctly configured). Connection for controluser as defined in your
configuration failed.
```

and when I see xampp manager it shows mysql service is stopped.

It's not even starting after so many retries from commands or GUI.  My logs can be seen [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/61906554/log.txt).

Please help as soon as possible.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install apache2 mysql-server mysql-client php5 phpmyadmin
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

This should complete the partial install of the components you need.  It should also upgrade the installed components.

Comment: it worked !! .. but there is still one problem I'm facing and that is phpmyadmin. I tried installing it by using following command : [ sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5-mysql phpmyadmin ] but it not working . Can you Help me with this too .. thanks for previous help James :)

Comment: Please check my updated answer.

Comment: same out put i get 

`sammy@sammy:~$ sudo apt-get install apache2 mysql-server mysql-client php5 phpmyadmin
[sudo] password for sammy: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package phpmyadmin
sammy@sammy:~$ 
`...... even i have tried updating apt-get

Comment: Which distro/version are you running that you're missing the phpmyadmin repository?  You can add the repository with:  "***sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tuxpoldo/phpmyadmin;sudo apt-get update***"  Then the command in the answer should work.

Comment: I'm using this version **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 32 bit**. Since I've installed it my update never goes well , i always face error 

but following you guidance I end up with this now 
`The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 phpmyadmin : Depends: php5-mcrypt but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Comment: Look at: http://askubuntu.com/questions/461975/i-cant-edit-update-remove-or-install-my-broken-packages/461989#461989

Answer (score 0):

You need stop mysql server which u have installed before xampp

sudo service mysql stop

Then restart xampp services

sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart

That's it